# Unable to add image to the top left edge of the cell in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have added the image to the top left of cell in `UICollectionView`.But the image is added to the inner side of the cell but not the outer side of the cell.Please tell me how can i add the image to the outer side of the cell.Below is the code for my implementation.

```
UIButton *delButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, delButtonSize, delButtonSize)];
delButton.center = CGPointMake(9, 10);
delButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[delButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross_30.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell addSubview:delButton];
[delButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteRecipe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

[image]

But i want like this

[image]

Comment: set `clipsToBounds` to NO

Answer (score 0):

add

delButton.clipsToBounds = NO;

***UPDATE*** ***Different Approach***

[image]
Maybe you can change you layout similar to this ?

Comment: or maybe changing cell.clipsToBounds = NO; ?